# OpenNMS sending multiple notification for the same event

Tags: slack, opennms

I have referred the following url to integrate OpenNMS with Slack.

```
# Drop this file in your OPENNMS_HOME/etc/opennms.properties.d directory

org.opennms.netmgt.notifd.slack.webhookURL=https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
org.opennms.netmgt.notifd.slack.username=UlfBot
org.opennms.netmgt.notifd.slack.iconURL=https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/7483547
org.opennms.netmgt.notifd.slack.channel=#AwesomeOps

# Then add this to OPENNMS_HOME/etc/notificationCommands.xml, and restart OpenNMS

    <command binary="false">
        <name>slack</name>
        <execute>org.opennms.netmgt.notifd.SlackNotificationStrategy</execute>
        <comment>class for sending messages to a Slack team channel for notifications</comment>
        <argument streamed="false">
            <switch>-subject</switch>
        </argument>    
        <argument streamed="false">
            <switch>-tm</switch>
        </argument>
    </command>
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/jeffgdotorg/83a3888c9b0b9275d35e02b79a054ff9

However, although it integrated the OpenNMS instance correctly, I receive 3 notifications on Slack for the same event on OpenNMS.

I am not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you have multiple role selected in "Configure Destination Paths"

- **Solution 1:**

Have only one role in Destination path for slack. Home-> Admin -> Configure Notifications -> Destination Paths - > Modify destination for slack. Select only one role in Initial target and finish.

[Solution 1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Sv0.png)

- **Solution 2:**

Even if you have multiple role in Initial targets, you can off the notification for other role and keep on for one role. Please see the attached image for it.

[Solution 2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3PI8.png)

Hope this resolves the issue of multiple notification.

-Kushal